# Problem regarding device driver development for sensor

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I want to develop a kernel device driver and user application for a specific sensor that uses I2C communication. Using reference code online, I have made the code below (with some omissions):

**User Application**

```
#include "gy30-values.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define WR_MODE _IOW('a','a',int*)
#define RD_L_VALUE_RAW _IOR('a','b',uint16_t*)

...

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd; 
    uint16_t light_value; 
    uint16_t light_value_raw_data;
    //printf("Initialized raw_data: %d", light_value_raw_data);
    int choice, mode;
    int meas_time, min_meas_time;

    //Open driver and device file
    printf("\nOpening Driver...\n");
        fd = open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR); 
    printf("fd: %d\n", fd);
        if(fd < 0) {
                printf("Cannot open device file...!\n");
                return -1;
        }
 
    ...

    //Writing mode to driver
       printf("Writing mode 0x%x to driver...\n",mode);
       ioctl(fd, WR_MODE, (int*) &mode);

    //Read values from sensor until user has pressed q.
    printf("Configuration complete.\n");    
       printf("Starting measurement process. Press q to exit\n");   
       while(getkey() != 113) {
      ioctl(fd, RD_L_VALUE_RAW, (uint16_t*) &light_value_raw_data);
      light_value = calculateLightValue(light_value_raw_data, mode);
      printf("Current sensing lux value: %d lux\n", light_value);
          usleep(meas_time);
       }
    printf("GY30 example finished.\n");
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

**Kernel code (IOCTL section)**

```
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
...

#define WR_MODE _IOW('a','a',int*)
#define RD_L_VALUE_RAW _IOR('a','b',uint16_t*)

...

int sensing_mode;

static long driver_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
         switch(cmd) {
                case WR_MODE:              
            if(copy_from_user(&sensing_mode ,(int*) arg, sizeof(sensing_mode)))
                        {
                printk("GY30: Writing Mode to Kernel : Error!\n");
                        } else {
                            printk("GY30: Mode = %d\n", sensing_mode);
            }
                        break;
                case RD_L_VALUE_RAW: ;
            uint16_t light_val;
            //printk("GY30: Mode = %d\n", sensing_mode);
            light_val = read_light_value_raw(sensing_mode);

            if(light_val < 0) {
                printk("GY30: Value invalid!\n");       
            }

                        if(copy_to_user((uint16_t*) arg, &light_val, sizeof(light_val)) )
                        {
                                printk("GY30: Reading Light Value to User App.: Err!\n");
                        } else {
                    printk("GY30: The value %d was copied!\n", light_val);
            }
                        break;
                default:
                        printk("Default: was the IOCTL call correct?\n");
                        break;
        }
        return 0;
}

...
```

Both the kernel and user code can compile without significant error (just a minor unrelated error). However, when I try to run the user application, it seems to ignore the ioctl command and doesn't measure the light value from the sensor (it just prints the value of the variable after initialization). I get an 'Inappropriate ioctl for device' error during runtime after modifying the code a little bit.

Other points to note:

- When I use the linux/ioctl.h library, it throws an 'implicit declaration of function ioctl' warning (which is why I am using the sys/ioctl.h line).
- The kernel release is 4.9.253-tegra (if it helps)
- The user application seems to work without ever communicating with the device driver (which I know because it doesn't print the messages in the kernel IOCTL function)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. `get an 'Inappropriate ioctl for device'` So what device have you registered? Please post more code from your kernel driver. `When I use the linux/ioctl.h library, it throws an 'implicit declaration of function ioctl'` Yes, userspace kernel headers != userspace headers. `linux/ioctl.h` are macros that are shared by both kernel and userspace.

Comment: /dev/i2c-1 is your i2c bus, not the i2c device so I'm pretty sure it doesn't implement your ioctl

Comment: Is it academical task? If not, you should use IIO subsystem and not using it will require a very good argument why.

Comment: Side note: The last parameter of the `_IOR`, `_IOW` or `_IOWR` should be the type of data the ioctl reads or writes, not a pointer to that type.

Comment: @AlexandreBelloni you were right, I changed the line to 

 `fd = open("/dev/gy30", O_RDWR);` 

and it works fine. @0andriy noted your comment and I will look into this. Thanks both.